# How to specify style sheets for my classes in QT

Tags: c++, qt, class, inheritance, qtstylesheets

I have a class that inherits from qframe， the "darksheetstyle" qss file is:

```
    /* (dot) .QFrame  fix #141, #126, #123 */
.QFrame {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #455364;
  /* No frame */
  /* HLine */
  /* HLine */
}

.QFrame[frameShape="0"] {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px transparent #455364;
}

.QFrame[frameShape="4"] {
  max-height: 2px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #455364;
}

.QFrame[frameShape="5"] {
  max-width: 2px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #455364;
}
```

the QFrame has no border, so I wrote my class qss in the same qss file:

```
BorderFrame {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #455364;
  /* No frame */
  /* HLine */
  /* HLine */
}
```

the cpp code is:

```
class ULTRA_PLOT_EXPORT BorderedFrame : public QFrame
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit BorderedFrame(QWidget* parent) : QFrame(parent)
        {
            setParent(parent);
        }
        ~BorderedFrame() override = default;
        BorderedFrame(const BorderedFrame&) = delete;
        BorderedFrame& operator=(const BorderedFrame&) = delete;
        BorderedFrame(BorderedFrame&&) = delete;
        BorderedFrame& operator=(BorderedFrame&&) = delete;
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override
        {
            QStyleOption opt;
            opt.initFrom(this);
            QPainter p(this);
            style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);//绘制样式
        }
    };
```

then, My own QFrame class still has no borders， how to fixed it ?

Comment: BorderFrame != BorderedFrame

Comment: what's your mean?

Comment: I mean that there is a typo because BorderFrame and BorderedFrame are not equal.

Comment: Oh,my fault. but i use the corect class name in in my project

Comment: Your example works fine for me when I correct the typo. Please provide a minimal, compilable example without any extra unneeded stuff (like e.g. the deleted functions - not needed at all in an example and also not needed in real life since an QObject can not be copied by design, the ctor calling setParent() is also not needed - QObject does it correctly when you pass the parent)

Comment: realy? i have no idea with it. i'll check my qss again

Comment: thank you! I have found the problem.  I put BorderedFrame in a namespace, so it isn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected for me:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class BorderedFrame : public QFrame
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  using QFrame::QFrame;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  app.setStyleSheet("BorderedFrame { border-radius: 4px; border: 2px solid #ff0000; }");
  BorderedFrame w;
  w.show();

  return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```